# Cannot update fragment's data (fragment in viewpager)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have 3 activites- A,B, and C. All these 3 activities have a viewpager. And these viewpagers have 1 fragment(this fragment is common to all viewpagers). The launcher activity is A, and pressing a button in A takes me to B, and pressing a button in B takes me to C.

A-> B -> C

Now the problem is when I update any data in C's fragment, it is not updated in A's and B's fragment. But if I update any data in A's fragment and then go to B, B's fragment will have updated data but vice versa is not happening.

Note: I' using a viewpager because I'll be adding more fragments in the future.

I assume the reason this is happening is because when C's fragment is updated, A's and B's fragment is having the old instance of the viewpager (or fragment). So, when I come back to A or B, the old data is being shown.

If this is the problem what is the best solution?

I have tried using viewpager.notifyDataSetChanged(),this works but messes up the views in the fragment.

Can anybody suggest an alternative?Thank you in advance!

Comment: try with onActivityResult()

Comment: Check this link for Communicating with Other Fragments https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html